# Mapping over a collection with a predicate including the first element on which predicate fails

Tags: kotlin, collections, sequence

I would like to `map` over a collection with a predicate such that:

1. mapping should stop if the predicate is false
2. the resulting collection must contain the element for which the predicate was false
3. no additional mapping should occur after the predicate was false.

There is [Sequence.takeWhile](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/take-while.html) which satisfies 1 and 3 **but not** 2.

An example with `takeWhile`:

```kotlin
val seq = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4).asSequence()
seq.map { println("mapping: $it"); it }
    .takeWhile { it < 3 }
    .also { println(it.toList()) }    }
```

The output is

```
mapping: 1
mapping: 2
mapping: 3
[1, 2]
```

I'd need the result to be `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Sounds like something you can write your own extension function for. I don't think this exists in the standard library.

Comment: Looks similar to Sweeper's answer, will have a look.

Comment: It should be .takeWhile { it < 4 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a thing in the standard library. If you want to stick to standard library functions, you most likely need to iterate the sequence twice.

This is something you can easily implement yourself:

```
fun <T> Sequence<T>.inclusivelyTakeWhile(predicate: (T) -> Boolean) = sequence {
    for (t in this@inclusivelyTakeWhile) {
        yield(t)
        if (!predicate(t)) {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Then doing:

```
seq.map { println("mapping: $it"); it }
    . inclusivelyTakeWhile { it < 3 }
    .also { println(it.toList()) }
```

produces the desired result.

Using the `sequence` function here probably adds some overhead, compared to the [standard library's implementation of `TakeWhileSequence`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/b65c477e68d2e4e3b635d63b7cdc61f41829d472/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Sequences.kt#L430). If you care about this, you can create a modified version of `TakeWhileSequence` and return that instead.